# Creating a instant search module for xcart with large MySQL database( millions of records) without using solr or elastic search?

Tags: search-engine, wildcard, x-cart

**Creating a instant search module for xcart with large MySQL database( millions of records) without using solr or elastic search?**

We have a x-cart 4.6.6 installation and we are looking to enable instant product name, description, sku, make, model, year, and some other relevant information.

The issue is our database is large(over 1 million products) and since it uses a % wildcard to start search its taking up to 6 seconds to receive results. Can anyone give me guidance on how to improve this or other options. There are 3 prebuilt solr plugins but there are to expensive and there sites are shaddy so I'm sure support is as well. What methods could be used to improve speed, as its essential to conversion rates. Please let me know any additional info your need to diagnose issue and solution. Thanks, Anthony.

For further clarification, We have a top left search box that uses JS & PHP to connect to mysql and pull results. Our developers have informed us since its using a wildcard for less defined searches like 2 letter searches its slowing it down.

Comment: Please don't use tags for certain libraries and platforms if your question is how to NOT use those software packages.

Answer (score 1):

As you may have noticed, MySQL's support for full-text search is very limited. Not only in terms of speed. [MySQL FULLTEXT indexing and searching functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) lack many important features that are now a must for any full fledged search engine: morphology, relevance tuning, faceted search, synonyms and more.

Since what you are asking is not just a full-text search, but rather a product search, features like promotions, spelling corrections and query suggestions could also be desirable.

I realize that you have stated in your question that you want to reach your goal without using Solr or Elastic Search, yet I would argue that it's practically impossible to build a fast and feature-rich product search engine written solely in PHP + MySQL.

I'm the creator of [CloudSearch](https://www.x-cart.com/extensions/addons/cloudsearch.html) - product search engine for X-Cart stores. During a several years of its development and evolution, we came up with a cloud architecture with a cluster of homogeneous servers handling search requests from X-Cart stores. This architecture allows us to serve thousands of clients, some of which have up to 1 million of products. Yet our average search request processing time is about 25 ms.

If you need a real fast and accurate product search for X-Cart store, I would recommend you to consider starting off with one of the robust full-text search systems: Solr, Elastic Search or Spinx. Solr and Elastic Search are the ones that I find the most feature-complete.

An other option would be to use one of the existing integrated solutions. Even with commercial services this can be a lot cheaper than building your own product search engine on top of Solr or Sphinx or other open source search engine.

Comment: Ok, so we decided to go with your product and it is the only true way to do this correctly. Now here is the next issue. We have a make model year selector and it has over 2.3 million combos. Can we modify the script to use your API to address that issue and can you guys also do customization. You can see our ticket at Message id: 1584585 in com center but it would be good to reply here as well.